# H2 database not working in SpringBoot test cases

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, h2

I have below test case in SpringBoot app with mentioned datasource configuration

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ComponentScan(#service package)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataSourceConfiguration.class)
public class IdTest{

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private MyRespository myRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProcessorService processorService;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    MyObject myObject;

    @Test
    void injectedComponentsAreNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(dataSource);
        assertNotNull(jdbcTemplate);
        assertNotNull(entityManager);
        assertNotNull(myRepository);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void invalidId() throws Exception {
        String resource = "/invalid/invalidId.xml";
        myObject= new MyObject();
        modifyPrivateField(myObject, "id", readFileToByteArray(resource));
        modifyPrivateField(myObject, "name", resource);

        MyObject mySavedObject = myRepository.save(myObject);
        ProcessingResult rsult = processorService.process(mySavedObject.getId());
        assertNotNull(rsult);
        assertEquals(ProcessingResult.ErrorCode.ILLEGAL_FORMAT_MANDATE_ID, rsult.getErrorCode());
        assertEquals(1, rsult.getVars().length);
        assertEquals("3805213", rsult.getVars()[0]);
    }

}
```

**DataSourceConfiguration.java**

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
            "#service package" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "DataSourceEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
    public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    
        @Value("${my.driverClassName}")
        private String driver;
    
        @Value("${my.url}")
        private String url;
    
        @Value("${my.username}")
        private String username;
    
        @Value("${my.password}")
        private String password;
    
        @Value("${my.dialect}")
        private String dialect;
    
        @Bean
        public DataSource unittestDataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driver);
            dataSourceBuilder.url(url);
            dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
            dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean DataSourceEntityManagerFactory(
                @Qualifier("unittestDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(),
                    new HashMap(), null);
            Builder factoryBuilder = builder.dataSource(datasource);
            factoryBuilder.packages("#service package");
            factoryBuilder.persistenceUnit("PU-unittest");
            factoryBuilder.jta(false);
    
            Map<String, String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
            additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
            factoryBuilder.properties(additionalProperties);
    
            return factoryBuilder.build();
        }
    }
```

**application.yml**

```yaml
    my:
     dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
     driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
     url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=ORACLE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
     username: sa
     password:
    
    spring:
     jpa: 
      hibernate:
       ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Test case executes without any error when I configure oracle database. However, when I configure H2 database (as above) I get error

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select PAS_CIO_SEQ1.nextval from[*] dual"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement: select PAS_CIO_SEQ1.nextval from dual [42001-200]`

What is the thing I am missing here? How to resolve this issue?

**NOTE:** I have tried with multiple dialects (Oracle, Oracle10g, h2 etc).

Comment: The `OracleDialect` will not work for H2 obviously. And no even in mode ORACLE it still is H2 doing some SQL mapping for Oracle not everything. Is there a reason to not use the default support in Spring Boot but work around that?

Comment: @M.Deinum As I mentioned, I tried with all dialects. By "default support in Spring Boot" do you mean using Oracle DB or `spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.driver` etc properties?

Comment: By using `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` which will replace the normal database out of the box. Without you needing to create a configuration etc. This will override the default `spring.datasource.url` (or rather ignore it).

Answer (score 0):

I would say the sequence is missing. Verify that it is created, and try without `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false` in case there is a problem with casing of the nextval column...